# AJAX call having jQuery-built query string with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, solr

Apache Solr asks that one of the GET parameters sent to it's endpoint is a name duplicated:

```
facet.range=price&facet.range=age
```

Documentation here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.range

In jQuery, how can I include that query string parameter (`facet.range`) twice?  I cannot make an object with duplicate keys, but this is along the lines of what I need to do:

```
context = {
    'facet.range': 'price',
    'facet.range': 'age', // This will be the only element in this dictionary as the key names are the same
}

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select',
    dataType:"jsonp",
    contentTypeString: 'application/json',
    jsonp:"json.wrf",
    data: context,
    success:function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `'facet.range': ['price', 'age']` in your params object and set `traditional` to true in the ajax call in order to enforce "traditional" serialization of parameters, that is `foo=1&foo=2` instead of `foo[]=1&foo[]=2`.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest answer. I'd hate to build GET queries manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery internally uses `$.param` for serializing forms, so you would be able to do the same:

```
data = $.param(
    { name: 'facet.range', value: 'price' }, 
    { name: 'facet.range', value: 'age' }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the arguments manually to the url.

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select?facet.range=price&facet.range=age', // Add other parameters in the url
       dataType:"jsonp",
       contentTypeString: 'application/json',
       jsonp:"json.wrf",
       success:function (data) {
           ...
       }
   });
```

Comment: Or, you can pass a query string to the `data` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way around that is to "hard code" the data as query string parameters instead of passing data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select?facet.range=price&facet.range=age',
    dataType:"jsonp",
    contentTypeString: 'application/json',
    jsonp:"json.wrf",
    data: null,
    success:function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I am unfamiliar with Apache Solr but I know you can just re-create the URL to pass the parameters

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select?'+ "facet.range=price&facet.range=age",
    success:function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```